# Remove "Name" field from Joomla registration form

Tags: joomla2.5

I would like to remove the Name field in the Joomla registration form.

I have tried editing the /com_users/models/forms/registration.xml

I've tried removing the field from the XML file and I've also tried to set it as 'optional'. Neither of these work. The is a registration failed message in the next page in either case.

Answer (score 1):

Found the instructions http://www.2createthatwebsite.com/tutorials/joomla-tutorials/remove-fields-joomla-registration-form

You need to edit the libraries/joomla/database/table/user.php file.

You need to edit the check() function.

In my case, I added a:

```
$this->name=$this->username;
```

at the beginning of the check function, that sets the username as the name, juse before saving.